# I invoke dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() to update UI ,this code couldn't work immediately,but work after several seconds sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsthread

Here is my code：

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
{
    [locker lock];
    UIApplication *sharedApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    if ([sharedApplication isIgnoringInteractionEvents] == NO) {
       [sharedApplication beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    }
    .........
    //data update

    [locker unlock];
    if ([sharedApplication isIgnoringInteractionEvents]) {
        [sharedApplication endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    }

    PLog(@"lock unlocked");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        PLog(@"reload block");
        //UI update
    });
});
```

The console log:

```
2015-10-12 16:08:02.012 [491:143698] last one.......
2015-10-12 16:08:02.012 [491:143698] lock unlocked
2015-10-12 16:08:10.762 [491:141942] reload block
2015-10-12 16:08:10.762 [491:141942] collecttion will reload
2015-10-12 16:08:10.778 [491:143664] Fast Image Cache: Generating thumbnails...
2015-10-12 16:08:10.862 Paidashi_Ipad[491:141942] Fast Image Cache: Generated thumbnails in 0.084789 seconds
```

just like above show it spend 8 second，add I add the third lib FastImageCache while do UI update

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, what could be is that some other (slow) code is running in the Main Thread as well.

Comment: Pause the app in the debugger during that 8 seconds and look at what the main thread is doing.

Comment: This case only happen while it push from a custom captrue viewcontroller sometimes,it works well when push from any other page.I have looked for mianThread through instrument,found that mainThread count more than100 Mb memory,but I don't know how to realease it.

Comment: You need to focus on one problem at a time.  If you want to deal with the delay, try my earlier suggestion.  If you want to deal with memory, that's (probably!) a different question.